# Noe4j : how to get property names with count of non-null or non-empty value for a given node label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

So there is a requirement of counting the number of occurrences of non null and non empty values of all properties for a given node label.

For example,

```
MATCH(p:Person) 
WHERE p.name IS NOT NULL and p.name <> "" 
RETURN COUNT(p.name);
```

This gives me a count for name properties for node label `Person`
I have to get the count of such other 200 properties for this node label. I am able to get the count of the properties but I am not sure for conditional count like the above. Anything would be helpful as I have just started learning neo4j.

The query I am using for all properties count is

```
MATCH(p:Person)
WITH p
UNWIND keys(p) as key
WITH key, COUNT(keys(p)) as cnt
RETURN DISTINCT key, cnt
ORDER BY key
```

What needs to be modified in the query? Or my query is wrong to start with. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are inferring the possible properties from the `Person` nodes in the `MATCH`, then you can get the count of non-empty properties with the following:

```sql
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND keys(p) AS key
WITH key, CASE WHEN p[key] <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isNonEmpty
RETURN key, sum(isNonEmpty) AS cnt
ORDER BY key
```

Note that because Neo4j treats null properties as non-existent, then if none of the nodes returned by the `MATCH` statement has the property, those properties can't be inferred.

The `CASE` can easily be adapted to exclude other property values from the count. For example, to exclude empty lists, you can write:

```sql
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND keys(p) AS key
WITH key, 
     CASE p[key]
       WHEN [] THEN 0 
       WHEN "" THEN 0
       WHEN 0 THEN 0
       ELSE 1 
     END AS isNonEmpty
RETURN key, sum(isNonEmpty) AS cnt
ORDER BY key
```

If you know the properties in advance because, for example, you know the schema, then you could provide them as a list or set of records. For example, if the properties were `'a'` through to `'g'`, you could use the following:

```sql
UNWIND ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'] AS key
MATCH (p)
WITH key, CASE WHEN p[key] <> "" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isNonEmpty
RETURN key, sum(isNonEmpty) AS cnt
ORDER BY key
```

Comment: I ran your query and got the response. One question though. This query doesn't include 0 occurences? For example if there is a property name ```bornIn``` which has empty value "" or null values only. It doesn't include in the list. I have 200 properties and it is returning 160 meaning 40 have null or empty values. But I want to add those 40 also with occurences 0. What clause I need to use for the same? And thank you for the query you provided.

Comment: OK I have updated the answer to count those as well.

Comment: how can we extend this query to add filters for not only empty values ```""```but also empty list ```[]``` and other types. i have tried your query extending the ```case``` clause with ```CASE WHEN p[key] <> "" THEN 1 
WHEN p[key] <> [] THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END AS isNonEmpty```
but this is not giving the right output

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to extend the `CASE` statement

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/) like `COUNT` already group by non-aggregating expressions like `key`, so `DISTINCT` is not needed. And comparisons to `NULL` are considered `false` by `WHERE`, so an explicit `NULL` test would be redundant.

Here is a query that uses:

- [ISEMPTY](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/predicate/#functions-isempty) to detect all "empty" properties (with `""`, `[]`, or `{}` values).
- [TOINTEGER](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-tointeger) to convert booleans to 1 (for `true`) or 0.

It will also return a `0` count for properties that are always empty.

```
MATCH (p:Person)
UNWIND KEYS(p) AS key
RETURN key, SUM(TOINTEGER(NOT ISEMPTY(p[key]))) AS cnt 
ORDER BY key
```

You should [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/planning-and-tuning/query-tuning/#how-do-i-profile-a-query) the queries in the proposed answers to your question see which one uses the fewest DB hits.

Also, if it makes sense, you should consider removing all properties that have an empty string value if they should be considered as non-existent. That would allow you to use evern simpler and faster queries.

Comment: thank you for your query. Your query gives similar output as finbar. it doesnt include the properties that have 0 occurences. For example if there is a property name ```bornIn``` which has empty value "" or null values only. It doesn't include in the list. how can we extend your query to add filters such as apart from checking empty value"" , we can also check empty list or empty objects. as properties may not be only type ```string``` .

Comment: See my updated answer. It will return a 0 count for properties that are always empty, and it will detect all types of "empty" values.